Why doesn't `text.replace('\n', ' ')` replace the newlines with spaces?
I'm trying to replace newline indicators (\n, as I understand) with spaces with the following line:
text.replace('\n', ' ')
however it doesn't work at all. The text that I'm getting is an output from pytesseract.
this is the full code with that line:
    if conjunction_variable is True:
        text.replace('\n', ' ')
        conjunctionJunction(text)


The str.replace() works by returning a new str, not by modifying the existing text. (btw, str in Python are immutable, i.e. cannot be changed)
See Python official docs: https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace

Return a copy of the string ...

So:
old_text = 'abc'
new_text = old_text.replace('b', 'x')

print(old_text)  # unchanged: abc
print(new_text)  # replaced: axc


Google is your friend. See this question. You need something like this:
text = text.replace('\n', ' ')

